# different arrays in one function

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am beginner in c++ and I have to right a function that ask the user to enter the values of the first element of five different arrays. For example array for student name, array for student id, and etc. The question here what would be the parameter of this function.

This is my attempt i declared the arrays to be global. I do not know where is the mistake.

```
const int SIZE=1000;
int studN[SIZE]; 
int id[SIZE]; 
string courseName[SIZE];
string courseSec[SIZE]; 
int regNom[SIZE];

void insertNew()
{ 
int index=0;
index++;
cout<<"Please enter the student name:  ";
cin>>studN[index];
cout<<"Please enter the student ID:  ";
cin>>id[index];
cout<<"Please enter the course name:  ";
cin>>courseName[index];
cout<<"Please enter the course section:  ";
cin>>courseSec[index];
cout<<"Please enter the registration number:  ";
cin>>regNom[index];
cout<<" Information stored"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: For studN use string data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly you want to write a function that will set values of elements of the arrays with a given index. The function can look the following way

```
bool Insert( int studN[], int id[], string courseName[], string courseSec[], int regNom, size_t size, size_t pos )
{
    if ( size <= pos ) return false;

    cout << "Please enter the student name:  ";
    cin >> studN[pos];
    // other stuff
    // ,,,

    return true;
}
```

But in any case it would be better to define one array of a structure or class that will contain corresponding fields.

Comment: can you please explain what is the size_t, because i'm gonna use it i have to explain to my teacher why i did so .

Comment: @user3138845 It is obvious that there is no any sense if an array would have a negative size. So usually for arrays sizes some unsigned integral type is used. size_t is defined as a typedef for some unsigned integral type. For example typedef unsigned int size_t; or typedef unsigned long size_t; You can simply substitute size_t for unsigned int in your code or even use type int. Only you should know that arrays may not have negative sizes.

Comment: Thank you so much. but the function call should it be like this:        Insert(studN , id, courseName, courseSec, int regNom, size_t, size_t )

Comment: @user3138845 Instead of the first size_t you should specify SIZE, the size of you arrays, and instead of the second size_t you should specify the index of an element you are going to initialize.

Comment: The same problem even when i used your method

Comment: When I entered the student name which is the first value of the first array in the black output window and when i press enter it started to show an infinite amount of words and numbers. it is some thing like when you have an infinite loop

Comment: Sorry it was because the type of student name it should be string . Sorry for bothering.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have declared the arrays as global variables, you need not provide any parameters to the function.

However, your index should be initialized once to 0 outside the function. This is because you do not want to over-write the values again and again at the same index = 1.

Also, after every `int` read operation, you should type `cin.ignore()` since the `\n` character resides in the input buffer and this interferes with further string reads.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a main() function to start the program. That's probably where you want the cin/cout to be.

Having the variables like you do is not optimal if you want to hide them so stuff them in the main {} with the rest of the code you have

Then you want to send these parameters that you have added to another function. Like

```
PrintStudents( int* studN, etc....) 
{

}
```

Note that you need to use pointers.

Comment: of course i have a main() function where i called this function. the problem is in this function i can't figure the mistake.